# XML Using Javascript - Compare Node Value

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml string i'll like to parse it and build a string with all nodes value.

```
    var test = "<monday>"+
  " <employee>"+
        "<name>Name 1</name>"+
        "<Serie>123</Serie>"+
        "<endTime>3:30 PM</endTime>"+
    "</employee>"+
   " <employee>"+
        "<name>Name 2</name>"+
        "<Serie>10 AM</Serie>"+
        "<endTime>3:30 PM</endTime>"+
     "</employee>"+
    "<employee>"+
        "<name>Name 1</name>"+
        "<Serie>12:30 PM</Serie>"+
        "<endTime>3:30 PM</endTime>"+
    "</employee>"+
"</monday>";
```

The string i need have to look like

```
name=Name 1&name1=Name 2&Serie=123&Serie1=10AM
```

If 2 name nodes (Name 1) have the same value ill like to get only one and get its value then build my string like this:

```
name=Name 1&name1=Name 2&Serie=123;1230&Serie1=10AM
```

I have tried something but is not working

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(test, "text/xml");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");

    var texte="";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        txt += x[i].nodeName +[i]+ "=" + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"&";

    }
    alert(txt);
```

Comment: *"I have tried something but is not working"*. The idea here is we help with code that isn't working, not write code for you. Show what you have tried so far

Comment: You are right... so far this is what i have tried. I have edited my post.

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery XML Parser?
[jQuery XML Parser](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: Not yet, just starting learnong javascript. i'll have a look

Comment: Fix typo `var texte="";` vs using `txt` in loop and alert

Comment: Seems to work here after fixing typo. https://jsfiddle.net/3j5sew3m/ Make sure you use browser console to check for errors

Comment: @charlietfl it's working but i don't have the result i need. 
I'll like to get this
name=Name 1&name1=Name 2&Serie=123;1230&Serie1=10AM

Comment: Is this closer? https://jsfiddle.net/3j5sew3m/1/

Comment: @charlietfl it is closer i have manage to build the scring. thank you for your help. 
Have you any idea on how i can compare to node ?  if for example 2 nodes like <name>Name 1 </name> have the same value i'll like to put only one in my tring.

Comment: Create a temporary storage object  and set the name value as keys. If that key already exists, skip it

Comment: @charlietfl thank you :)